# Repeatable input fields for settings page

Tags: jquery, forms

I am trying to create a plugin, in which i wanna use repeatable input fields in the settings page. I have found many sample codes online regarding repeatable input fields but only for post/page edit screen.

My code is here: http://pastebin.com/fiktsMrS

As you might see, i am using 'static' input fields

```
<!-- Textbox Control -->
<tr><th scope="row">Track 1</th><td><input type="text" size="200" name="fr_options[txt_1]" value="<?php echo $options['txt_1']; ?>" /></td></tr>
<tr><th scope="row">Track 2</th><td><input type="text" size="200" name="fr_options[txt_2]" value="<?php echo $options['txt_2']; ?>" /></td></tr>
<tr><th scope="row">Track 3</th><td><input type="text" size="200" name="fr_options[txt_3]" value="<?php echo $options['txt_3']; ?>" /></td></tr>
<tr><th scope="row">Track 4</th><td><input type="text" size="200" name="fr_options[txt_4]" value="<?php echo $options['txt_4']; ?>" /></td></tr>
<tr><th scope="row">Track 5</th><td><input type="text" size="200" name="fr_options[txt_5]" value="<?php echo $options['txt_5']; ?>" /></td></tr>
```

While all i want to do is have one input field, and an +ADD button next to it, which will create another one, and when i click save changes, it saves all the values of all the inputs.

Something similar can be found [here](http://en.bainternet.info/2012/my-options-panel) but it seems too complicated when i only want one repeatable input field.

Comment: I have answered this question, because I had very similar code to the below lying around and figured "might as well". That being done, let me inform you that I do not all see how this question is specific to WP. This could very well be implemented in another environment in exactly the same fashion. Both my answer as well as your code above reflect that. Close voting as "off topic".

Comment: ... or migration by a certain busy moderator might be feasible as well.

Comment: It was just unclear to me how wordpress is able to save each input field's data, and that's why i thought it is relevant to wordpress.
Should have formulated the question differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The PHP

```
$output = '<div class="repeatable-wrap">' .
    '<ul id="tracks-repeatable" class="repeatable-fields-list">';
if ( ! empty( $options ) ) {
    $i = 1;
    foreach( $options as $option ) {
        $output .= '<li>' .
            '<input type="text" name="fr_options[txt_'.$i.']"' .
                'value="' . $options['txt_'.$i] .'" size="200" />' .
            '<a class="repeatable-field-remove button" href="#">REMOVE</a>' .
            '</li>';
        $i++;
    }
} else {
    $output .= '<li>' .
        '<input type="text" name="fr_options[txt_1]" value="" size="200" />' .
        '<a class="repeatable-field-remove button" href="#">REMOVE</a>' .
        '</li>';
}
$output .= '</ul></div>' .
    '<a class="repeatable-field-add button" href="#">ADD</a>';
echo $output;
```

If your `$options` array contains more than just the fields you will have to tackle the above loop differently. The rest still applies.

### The jQuery

```
jQuery('.repeatable-field-add').click(function() {
    var theField = jQuery(this).closest('div.repeatable-wrap')
        .find('.repeatable-fields-list li:last').clone(true);
    var theLocation = jQuery(this).closest('div.repeatable-wrap')
        .find('.repeatable-fields-list li:last');
    /* the 2 linebreaks before the .find methods
        are for presentation reasons here only */
    jQuery('input', theField).val('').attr('name', function(index, name) {
        return name.replace(/(\d+)/, function(fullMatch, n) {
            return Number(n) + 1;
        });
    });
    theField.insertAfter(theLocation, jQuery(this).closest('div.repeatable-wrap'));
    var fieldsCount = jQuery('.repeatable-field-remove').length;
    if( fieldsCount > 1 ) {
        jQuery('.repeatable-field-remove').css('display','inline');
    }
    return false;
});

jQuery('.repeatable-field-remove').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).parent().remove();
    var fieldsCount = jQuery('.repeatable-field-remove').length;
    if( fieldsCount == 1 ) {
        jQuery('.repeatable-field-remove').css('display','none');
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the code! It was just unclear to me how wordpress is able to save each input field's data, and that's why i thought it is relevant to wordpress.